# Как закодировать ссылки на CSS и JS в base64?

Tags: base64, php, javascript

Есть две ссылки на стили и скрипты:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sait.com/dir/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sait.com/dir/scripts.js"></script>
```

Закодировать ссылки можно функцией PHP base64_encode.
Как нужно вставлять ссылки на стили и скрипты, чтобы они так и остались закодированными
внешне для пользователя, но браузер их понимал?

Comment: можно поиграть с апач реврайтом

Comment: Знать бы, что это такое ещё.

Comment: Пытаться скрыть ссылки на скрипт и стили от пользователя бессмысленно. В JS не должно быть ничего что может каким-либо образом повлиять на безопасность вашего проекта, а в CSS в принципе нет ничего опасного. Какова цель сокрытия ссылок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого придумали такую штуку как [обфускация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%E1%F4%F3%F1%EA%E0%F6%E8%FF). Главное правильно использовать. Чтобы обфусцировать эти 2 строки, можно воспользоваться http://htmlobfuscator.com . В исходном коде они будут закодированы, но в ресурсах F12 (в хроме), пользователь сможет вытащить данные как минимум из CSS, а JS код тоже можно обфусцировать. Хотя наверняка есть "обфускаторы" и для CSS

Comment: Для css есть сжатие, которое делает его чтение очень проблематичным, но через инспектор браузера всё равно можно посмотреть тот или иной стиль css для элемента

Answer (score 0):

Забудьте эту идею, она не принесет пользы, если пользователь захочет он узнает их без проблем, а себе вы только время уменьшите. Я не против вашей идеи, я за сохранность вашего времени!